# Pdfsharp save command doesn't throw exception in release version

Tags: file-permissions, pdfsharp

I'm creating a PDF document with Pdfsharp. Within a catch-try block I'm saving it to disk and then open the file with

```
document.Save("path")
Process.Start("path")
```

When in debug mode in Visual Studio it throws the exception as expected when saving to a location that I don't have permission to. When I run the installed version though, it doesn't throw an exception, but it tries to open the file which of course doesn't exist.

What's the reason for these different behaviors, and how do I get it to work as expected in the release version?

Comment: Which PDFsharp version do you use and how? Do you use NuGet packages, references to assemblies, or references to projects in VS?

Comment: Create an MCVE and provide information how to replicate the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm using version 1.32.2608.0 of PDFsharp.

Comment: I just figured out that I can see all the files (that I thought didn't exist) in my applications Save As dialog. I can't see them in the File Explorer however. When I try to copy a file to that location in File Explorer it asks for admin privileges. So my application seems to be in some twilight zone about the permissions for that directory, which is really confusing.